# django models storing request responses

Tags: python, django, django-models

I'm trying to save the details of responses from apis (typically undocumented).

The api's are likely to change over time and I will re request the data from them periodically which often is likely to have no change.
I therefore just want to save responses when they change and a time stamp when I last checked the response with the api.

I did start to model via the Django ORM, but I've most likely make it overly complicated trying to normalise the data.

Requests can be as usual, plain GET request, GET with query or POST with data. 
Responses should really be unique to a url (scheme, hostname and path), and query or payload, but I'm not sure how to best model this. And I feel the response JSON or text has a many 2 one relationship with the response.   However I feel there must be a simpler way as I really just started with not wanting to duplicate the storage of responses more than necessary as mentioned above.

```
class Request(models.Model):
    scheme = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    hostname = models.TextField()
    path = models.TextField(null=True)
    method = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    headers = models.TextField()

class Meta:
    unique_together = ('scheme', 'hostname', 'path', 'method')

def __str__(self):
    return self.url


class RequestQuery(models.Model):
    request = models.ForeignKey(Request)
    query = models.TextField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.query


class RequestPayload(models.Model):
    request = models.ForeignKey(Request)
    payload = models.TextField()  

    def __str__(self):
        return self.payload


class Response(models.Model):
    request = models.ForeignKey(Request)
    query = models.ForeignKey(RequestQuery, null=True)
    payload = models.ForeignKey(RequestPayload, null=True)
    headers = models.TextField()
    status_code = models.IntegerField()
    json = JSONField(null=True)  # stores in either json or text depending on if valid json
    text = models.TextField(null=True)

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ('request', 'status_code')

    def _str_(self):
        return str(self.request.url) + str(self.status_code)


class ResponseHistory(models.Model):
    time_stamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    response = models.ForeignKey(Response)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.time_stamp
```

Comment: Your question is not very clear. Can you answer the following: (1) Is the API making a call to your app and POSTing data to a URL you are listening to ? (2) Is you app calling the API url to GET data and also you POST / UPDATE back to that API by calling their API path ?  This may help to understand what you mean by response / request, as some of your text suggests the API is sending you a response.  I would consider your APP receiving a REQUEST and what your app sends back as the RESPONSE (seeing thing from your side not the API).

Comment: Thanks, sorry for being unclear.  This is about external Apis which I'm calling and getting data from which I wish to save.  I retrieve  data from the external API via a GET or a POSt request.  So (1) no , (2) yes but no update the POST is just used for data retrieval without having to send data openly in a GET query.  And lastly no this isn't about my app being an API and receiving a request it's only about it retrieving data and talking to external api's. (Ie my app is the API client) Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for the additional info.  So just sharing a couple of thoughts : (1) I would probably not use the Request as model name so as not to conflict with the django request object namespace. (2) I don't see why it would be any issue to store the entire querystring as-is from the API and still be able to map to your model data via a modelForm the individual data points. (3) Review another widely used django model and how they implemented the API calls. One that comes to mind is django-paypal that has a similar pattern of the app calling API url, but also the API POST back data to the app.